# Determining The Radius of Convergence for Complex Rational Function with E xponentials

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

If I have the following function:

$$f(x)=\frac{xe^{-x/3}}{e^{x/3}+w_3^2e^{w_3x/3}+w_3e^{w_3^2x/3}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{A_n}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

here, $w_3$ is the third root of unity, $e^\frac{2i\pi}{3}$.  How would I go about determining the radius of convergence?  I've done a little footwork to find the $A_n$ but it yields a recursive form.  I know that

$$A_0=1; A_n=-\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+1}{k}A_kB_{n+1-k}$$
where

$$B_n=\frac{1}{3^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(1+w_3^{k+2}+w_3^{2k+1}\right)$$

I would need $x<\frac{n!}{A_n}$ but I'm not sure how to approach this with recursive A_k.  What should I do?

Comment: What is $w_3$? (I'm guessing $\exp(2\pi i/3)$?

Comment: yes, I'm sorry...I meant to put that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function has a removable singularity at $z=0$ and poles at other points where the denominator vanishes but is otherwise holomorphic as a function of a complex variable $z$. I don't think
$$
\exp(z/3) + \omega^2 \exp (z\omega/3) + \omega \exp( z\omega^2/3) = 0
$$
(with $\omega = \exp(2\pi i/3)$) can be solved algebraically, but numerical computations puts the zeros closest to the origin at $z \approx 4.5251 \pm 7.8377i$ which would make the radius of convergence $\approx 9.0502$.

Comment: Awesome.  On a side note, do you think this function can be continued analytically or will I be stuck in this circle due to the nature of the poles?

Comment: @Lalaloopsy Which function? $f$ is already analytic off the zeros in the denominator.

Comment: You're right.  I see.  Thank you!